# Keyboard not working using Teamviewer 9

Tags: windows, remote-access

I am using teamviewer 9 on my laptop (windows 7) to log-in remotely to windows 8. After I log-in I cannot use my keyboard, however my mouse works fine. I have tried going to actions and clicking send remote key combinations but still not able to type, any idea?

The environment are following

```
Teamviewer version: 9.0.24951 (both to 2 pc)
Teamviewer license: Free (both to 2 pc)
Windows edition: windows 7 home basic (my pc)
Windows edition: windows 8 (target pc)
```

Comment: Thank you Sankumarsingh for the help.

Comment: Thanks for all. this issue resolved internal, the problem is the connection between the 2 pc. Thanks again.

Comment: May I ask what exactly you did to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and solved it by disabling UDP from Extras-->Options-->Advanced, scroll down, you will find it.

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
This issue resolved on its own.
I Think the problem is the network connection from my site or the target site.
When i tried yo disable and connect more than once, the problem resolved.
Thanks again.

Comment: I have had the same problem and the issue is resolved on its own too... Both computer use Teamviewer 9 and OS is Ubuntu Linux; 12.04 at the target and 13.10 at the local... But I doubt that it has something to do with network connection...

Comment: Thank you, this suggestion solved it, made my day!

Comment: I switched from Bridged Network mode to NAT Network mode and it worked!